# Shopify store - Upload order details to remote server on success page

Tags: xml, csv, ftp, shopify, shopify-template

This is my first time working on the Shopify store. I've been able to change the UI by customizing the template file. I need to customize the order success page. For that, I'm using admin/settings/checkout->Order Processing->Additional scripts to inject the liquid code. Once the order is successfully created I want to get the order/customer details in CSV/XML format and upload it to remote FTP. Is it possible?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But instead of issuing any AJAX call from Order status page, it is recommended to use [Shopify Webhooks](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/events/webhook). For your particular scenario, you need to listen to Order Create webhook. Anytime a new Order is created, you will receive a payload on your webhook handler that will have the Order and Customer information.

Sample Data for Order Create webhook

```
{
  "id": 820982911946154508,
  "email": "jon@doe.ca",
  "closed_at": null,
  "created_at": "2019-10-03T16:11:21-04:00",
  "updated_at": "2019-10-03T16:11:21-04:00",
  "number": 234,
  "note": null,
  "token": "123456abcd",
  "gateway": null,
  "test": true,
  "total_price": "403.00",
  "subtotal_price": "393.00",
  "total_weight": 0,
  "total_tax": "0.00",
  "taxes_included": false,
  "currency": "USD",
  "financial_status": "voided",
  "confirmed": false,
  "total_discounts": "5.00",
  "total_line_items_price": "398.00",
  "cart_token": null,
  "buyer_accepts_marketing": true,
  "name": "#9999",
  "referring_site": null,
  "landing_site": null,
  "cancelled_at": "2019-10-03T16:11:21-04:00",
  "cancel_reason": "customer",
  "total_price_usd": null,
  "checkout_token": null,
  "reference": null,
  "user_id": null,
  "location_id": null,
  "source_identifier": null,
  "source_url": null,
  "processed_at": null,
  "device_id": null,
  "phone": null,
  "customer_locale": "en",
  "app_id": null,
  "browser_ip": null,
  "landing_site_ref": null,
  "order_number": 1234,
  "discount_applications": [
    {
      "type": "manual",
      "value": "5.0",
      "value_type": "fixed_amount",
      "allocation_method": "one",
      "target_selection": "explicit",
      "target_type": "line_item",
      "description": "Discount",
      "title": "Discount"
    }
  ],
  "discount_codes": [
  ],
  "note_attributes": [
  ],
  "payment_gateway_names": [
    "visa",
    "bogus"
  ],
  "processing_method": "",
  "checkout_id": null,
  "source_name": "web",
  "fulfillment_status": "pending",
  "tax_lines": [
  ],
  "tags": "",
  "contact_email": "jon@doe.ca",
  "order_status_url": "https:\/\/apple.myshopify.com\/690933842\/orders\/123456abcd\/authenticate?key=abcdefg",
  "presentment_currency": "USD",
  "total_line_items_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "398.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "398.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_discounts_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "5.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "5.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_shipping_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "10.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "10.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "subtotal_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "393.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "393.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_price_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "403.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "403.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "total_tax_set": {
    "shop_money": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    },
    "presentment_money": {
      "amount": "0.00",
      "currency_code": "USD"
    }
  },
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 866550311766439020,
      "variant_id": 808950810,
      "title": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "quantity": 1,
      "sku": "IPOD2008PINK",
      "variant_title": null,
      "vendor": null,
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "product_id": 632910392,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "taxable": true,
      "gift_card": false,
      "name": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
      "properties": [
      ],
      "product_exists": true,
      "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
      "grams": 567,
      "price": "199.00",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "fulfillment_status": null,
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "total_discount_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "0.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "0.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discount_allocations": [
      ],
      "tax_lines": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 141249953214522974,
      "variant_id": 808950810,
      "title": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "quantity": 1,
      "sku": "IPOD2008PINK",
      "variant_title": null,
      "vendor": null,
      "fulfillment_service": "manual",
      "product_id": 632910392,
      "requires_shipping": true,
      "taxable": true,
      "gift_card": false,
      "name": "IPod Nano - 8GB",
      "variant_inventory_management": "shopify",
      "properties": [
      ],
      "product_exists": true,
      "fulfillable_quantity": 1,
      "grams": 567,
      "price": "199.00",
      "total_discount": "5.00",
      "fulfillment_status": null,
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "199.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "total_discount_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "5.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "5.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discount_allocations": [
        {
          "amount": "5.00",
          "discount_application_index": 0,
          "amount_set": {
            "shop_money": {
              "amount": "5.00",
              "currency_code": "USD"
            },
            "presentment_money": {
              "amount": "5.00",
              "currency_code": "USD"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "tax_lines": [
      ]
    }
  ],
  "shipping_lines": [
    {
      "id": 271878346596884015,
      "title": "Generic Shipping",
      "price": "10.00",
      "code": null,
      "source": "shopify",
      "phone": null,
      "requested_fulfillment_service_id": null,
      "delivery_category": null,
      "carrier_identifier": null,
      "discounted_price": "10.00",
      "price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discounted_price_set": {
        "shop_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        },
        "presentment_money": {
          "amount": "10.00",
          "currency_code": "USD"
        }
      },
      "discount_allocations": [
      ],
      "tax_lines": [
      ]
    }
  ],
  "billing_address": {
    "first_name": "Bob",
    "address1": "123 Billing Street",
    "phone": "555-555-BILL",
    "city": "Billtown",
    "zip": "K2P0B0",
    "province": "Kentucky",
    "country": "United States",
    "last_name": "Biller",
    "address2": null,
    "company": "My Company",
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "name": "Bob Biller",
    "country_code": "US",
    "province_code": "KY"
  },
  "shipping_address": {
    "first_name": "Steve",
    "address1": "123 Shipping Street",
    "phone": "555-555-SHIP",
    "city": "Shippington",
    "zip": "40003",
    "province": "Kentucky",
    "country": "United States",
    "last_name": "Shipper",
    "address2": null,
    "company": "Shipping Company",
    "latitude": null,
    "longitude": null,
    "name": "Steve Shipper",
    "country_code": "US",
    "province_code": "KY"
  },
  "fulfillments": [
  ],
  "refunds": [
  ],
  "customer": {
    "id": 115310627314723954,
    "email": "john@test.com",
    "accepts_marketing": false,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "orders_count": 0,
    "state": "disabled",
    "total_spent": "0.00",
    "last_order_id": null,
    "note": null,
    "verified_email": true,
    "multipass_identifier": null,
    "tax_exempt": false,
    "phone": null,
    "tags": "",
    "last_order_name": null,
    "currency": "USD",
    "accepts_marketing_updated_at": null,
    "marketing_opt_in_level": null,
    "default_address": {
      "id": 715243470612851245,
      "customer_id": 115310627314723954,
      "first_name": null,
      "last_name": null,
      "company": null,
      "address1": "123 Elm St.",
      "address2": null,
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "country": "Canada",
      "zip": "K2H7A8",
      "phone": "123-123-1234",
      "name": "",
      "province_code": "ON",
      "country_code": "CA",
      "country_name": "Canada",
      "default": true
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have this data, you can save it in some database, create CSV, upload to FTP or whatever you need.

[Get Started with Shopify Webhooks](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/webhooks)

Comment: Webhook method seems pretty good but i managed to get order data some other way. I'm using additional script option from admin panel to add code like this 

{{ order_number }}
{% for line in checkout.line_items %}
    {{ line.title }} 
  {% endfor %}

It seems to be working fine. I can't seem to able to find a way to create a remote FTP connection and upload the CSV file.

Comment: That is why, I have mentioned the recommended approach.. What you are trying to do is pretty fragile and will fail most of the time. You cannot save FTP credentials anywhere securely on client side and I don't know of any viable approach to create FTP connection from Client side JavaScript.

Comment: I looked into the webhook and it seems i can use the order creation event webhook and post the payload to remote URL where i can write code in PHP to create FTP and upload the file. I'll try this approach and see if it works.